# Single sign-on App

Tags: login, errors

We're implementing a "single session" solution in our mobile app ecosystem in order to avoid the case of users logging in with the same account and running more than one session on multiple devices. Starting a new session i.e. signing in with the same account on a new device will result with a message (for example, a full-screen modal dialog) on the other device that will force the user to log out / terminate the previous session.

Any examples of similar UX flows, or ideas for what kind of language should this message contain in order to keep it clear and friendly?

Thanks!
G

Comment: I can think of apps such as Evernote, Spotify and Netflix with a similar feature. In case you want to check them for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at Spotify, and what they seem to be doing is to let you choose which of the two sessions should take over... depending on the context, this could be a better UX but probably a bit more expensive from a technical perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just prevent the user from doing anything else on the "deactivated" device (i.e. full screen modal, as you mentioned) with wording that "You may only be signed in on one device at a time." Include options to go to your site home (if applicable) or Sign In on this device again.

Depending on how strict your site's security needs to be, you might also consider providing an option to change their password.

Consider the following mockup. As always, user testing should quickly be able to tell you if this design is understood by your users.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK5PbH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>